# When using testing-library with Vue, what is the best way to confirm an element is hidden by v-show?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, testing-library, vue-testing-library

When using [testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/intro/) with Vue it is easy to check if an element is not present in the DOM.

For example when [v-if](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if) for the element is `false`:

```js
element = screen.queryByTestId("my-element")
expect(element).toBeNull()
```

However when using [v-show](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-show) the element isn't removed from the DOM, it is toggled via an inline style of `display: none`, so the above won't work.

I can do something like this:

```js
element = screen.queryByTestId("my-element")
expect(element.style.display).toEqual("none")
```

But this feels somewhat brittle. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

From `@testing-library/vue`'s [Quickstart](https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/intro/#quickstart:%7E:text=You%20may%20also%20be%20interested%20in%20installing%20%40testing%2Dlibrary/jest%2Ddom%20so%20you%20can%20use%20the%20custom%20Jest%20matchers%20for%20the%20DOM.):

> You may also be interested in installing [@testing-library/jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#readme) so you can use the custom Jest matchers for the DOM.

---

The matchers contain [.toBeVisible()](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/blob/main/src/to-be-visible.js#L40), [described as](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/testing-library__jest-dom/matchers.d.ts#L29):

> This allows you to check if an element is currently visible to the user.
>
> An element is visible if **all** the following conditions are met:
>
> - it does not have its css property `display` set to `none`
> - it does not have its css property `visibility` set to either `hidden` or `collapse`
> - it does not have its css property `opacity` set to `0`
>   its parent element is also visible (and so on up to the top of the DOM tree)
> - it does not have the `hidden` attribute
> - if `<details />` it has the `open` attribute

---

Note: `jest-dom` doesn't care what framework you use. It evaluates HTML & CSS values, regardless of what directives generate those values. HTML and CSS output is what the user's browser receives.

Side-note: since you mentioned it, checking if an element is in DOM should be done with `expect(queryBy*(*))[.not].toBeInTheDocument()`.
In the latest version of `@testing-library`, which contains very helpful linting rules, the recommendation is to use `getBy*` queries for asserting presence in DOM and `queryBy*` for asserting absence.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I couldn't use jest-dom because I'm using vitest, but it looks like there may be a workaround: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/using-testing-library-jest-dom-with-vitest/